# Extract values from javascript object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, variables, extract

I am just learning to code so I can become a developer. My interest in JavaScript and I'm needing help to extract values from a JavaScript object and assign values as variables. Please see below:

```js
var members = {
  "Name": "Jake Bayliss",
  "Name": "Daryl Tripp",
  "Name": "Tom McKenzie",
  "Name": "George Bell",
  "Name": "Ally Young"
};
```

I need to extract the values in this sample data in the following format:

```js
var member1 = "Jake Bayliss";
var member2 = "Daryl Tripp";
var member3 = "Tom McKenzie";
var member4 = "George Bell";
var member5 = "Name":"Ally Young";
var count = //how do I count members?
```

I have tried to extract the values but I don't think I'm doing it right.

Comment: `members` is not a valid JavaScript object; keys must be unique. Can you elaborate on the context in which you would need these variables created dynamically when they are *much* more accessible/scalable in an Array or Array-like structure?

Comment: I did not mean members is a JavaScript object. I don't know JavasCript, I'm just learning. When I say members, I'm actually referring to members as in members of a club, team, group.

Comment: "*I did not mean members is a JavaScript object*" Then why have you expressed it as such? You've declared `members`, a JavaScript variable, as an Object in your snippet. However, the object itself is invalid because you've got multiple `Name` keys. Can you address the questions as I've posed them in my initial comment?

Comment: I'm learning and just need to know how to extract the values from that object and assign each as a variable. My knowledge is not like yours which explains why you are having to ask me these question. I'm a noobie

Comment: That's precisely the problem, though - you *can't* "*extract the values from that object*", because all the values themselves but the last one won't be retained as you've elected to build the object itself with duplicative keys. Only the last entry (`Ally Young`) will be retained in the object you've provided.

Comment: var members = {
  "Name1": "Jake Bayliss",
  "Name2": "Daryl Tripp",
  "Name3": "Tom McKenzie",
  "Name4": "George Bell",
  "Name5": "Ally Young"
};

Comment: Can you also elaborate in this instance why `member5` would be set to the (invalid) value of `"Name":"Ally Young"`, but the rest are simply the value for the keys?

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean and I've just learned about using unique keys. Thanks for the lesson.

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused about last question. Perhaps, I've done my example object all wrong. It's why I had to ask question as I know very little.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is an array. In this case you have something that should be an array of member names. To get the count you can just get the length of the array with .length. To assign the contents of the array to individual variables you can use array destructuring.

Here's what the code would look like:

```
const memberNames = [
  "Jake Bayliss",
  "Daryl Tripp",
  "Tom McKenzie",
  "George Bell",
  "Ally Young"
];

const [member1, member2, member3, member4, member5] = memberNames
const count = memberNames.length
```

This will create an object called members with an arbitrary number of properties, named member1, member2, member3 etc.

```
const members = memberNames.reduce((previous, memberName, index)=>({
  ...previous,
  ['member'+(index+1)]: memberName
}),{})
```

Result:

```
{
  member1: 'Jake Bayliss',
  member2: 'Daryl Tripp',
  member3: 'Tom McKenzie',
  member4: 'George Bell',
  member5: 'Ally Young'
}
```

You'll be able to use the dot operator on members to get each value. E.g. members.member1

Comment: Thank you @SteveGreenley - I really appreciate your patience and support with what I needed. One quick question, how would I automatically assign array values as variables based on the count. This const [member1, member2, member3, member4, member5] = memberNames works if I know object has five members. What if it's more?

Comment: While you can't create variables with dynamic names, you can assign dynamic properties to an object. This fragment of code will create an object called members with a series of properties: member1, member2, member3, etc. : const members = memberNames.reduce((previous, memberName, index)=>({
  ...previous,
  ['member'+(index+1)]: memberName
}),{}) (I've updated the answer with the above code as that allows nicer code formatting than is possible in the comments)